# GWT flowchart/tree library without flash

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, charts, svg

Does anyone know of a charting library that supports flowcharts (trees) but doesn't use any browser plugins like Flash to do so (SVG is okay)?

I've found RaphaelGWT (http://code.google.com/p/raphaelgwt/) and GChart (http://code.google.com/p/clientsidegchart/), but neither inherently supports flowcharts.

Before I roll my own solution, I'd like to check with the SO community.

Thank you,

z.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any GWT charting library which supports flowcharts.
However you could take a ["normal" JS charting library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558972/javascript-flowchart-library-for-workflow-visualization) which supports flowcharts and use it in GWT via JSNI.

In case you want to roll your own solution you could also check out [Protovis](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/) and [Protovis-GWT](http://code.google.com/p/choosel/wiki/ProtovisGWT) respectively (Protovis uses SVG).

Apparently somebody used Protovis to implement a flowchart described [here](http://www.limscoder.com/2011/04/using-protovis-to-create-simple-flow.html). Maybe it is of use to you.